# Making a function for fopen

Tags: php

how can I make a function for fopen. Here is the code:

```
    $url = 'http://url.com';
    $handle = @fopen($url, 'r');
    if ($handle) {
        $result = fgets($handle, 1024);     
        fclose($handle);
    }
    $allData = explode(',',$result); 
    $d1 = $allData[1];
    $d2 = $allData[2];
    $d3 = $allData[3];
```

Example of what I did. Here is the code:

```
 function something(){
    $url = 'http://url.com';
    $handle = @fopen($url, 'r');
    if ($handle) {
        $result = fgets($handle, 1024);     
        fclose($handle);
    }
    $allData = explode(',',$result); 
    $d1 = $allData[1];
    $d2 = $allData[2];
    $d3 = $allData[3];  
 }

 $sql = "INSERT INTO s (d1, d2, d3) VALUES ('".$d1."', '".$d2."', '".$d2."')";
```

So I get my data but I wanted to put it inside a function. The issue that I get when I put it inside a function is that I can only return one value. What can I do? Is there a way to put it inside a function?

Comment: *"What can I do?"* - Show us what you tried.

Comment: Why not to return $allData?..

Comment: a regular function, but I am only being allowed to use the function once when using it with an INSERT SQL

Comment: Then it sounds to be a scope issue. Again, show us what you tried.

Comment: As per your edit, that doesn't reflect what you said about your INSERT SQL.

Comment: I am trying to execute the function and not returning anything leaving the variables to be gathered solemnly. Issue is that sql does not seem to gather more than 1 properly, even if its a foreach statement

Comment: You've got some answers below. See what that says. It's a scope issue, just like I said earlier.

Comment: Thanks no luck....I will have to look closer to the issue....

Answer (score 0):

Your function can return an array:

```
return array($d1, $d2, $d3);
```

Then the caller can do:

```
list ($var1, $var2, $var3) = something();
```

Or you can define the function to take reference arguments:

```
function something (&$d1, &$d2, &$d3) {
    ...
}
```

Then it can be called as:

```
something ($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just return whole `$allData` array

```
function something(){
   $url = 'http://url.com';
   $handle = @fopen($url, 'r');
   if ($handle) {
       $result = fgets($handle, 1024);     
       fclose($handle);
   }
   return explode(',',$result);   
}

$allData = something();

$d1 = $allData[1];
$d2 = $allData[2];
$d3 = $allData[3];
```